# Why fsharp autogenerated gethashcode generates too many collisions?

Tags: f#

In our fsharp code autogenerated gethashcode implementation shows very bad performance and big collisions rate. Is it a problem in fsharp implementation of gethashcode generator or just an edge case?

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

let check keys e name =
    let dict =  new Dictionary<_,_>(Array.length keys, e)//, HashIdentity.Structural)
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
    let add k = dict.Add(k, 1.02)
    Array.iter add keys    
    stopWatch.Stop()
    let hsahes = new HashSet<int>()
    let add_hash x =  hsahes.Add(e.GetHashCode(x)) |> not
    let collisions = Array.filter add_hash keys |> Array.length
    printfn "%s %f sec %f collisions" name stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds (double(collisions) / double(keys.Length))

type StructTuple<'T,'T2> =
   struct
      val fst: 'T
      val snd : 'T2
      new(fst: 'T, snd : 'T2) = {fst = fst; snd = snd}
   end

let bad_keys = seq{
    let rnd = new Random();
    while true do
        let j = uint32(rnd.Next(0, 3346862))
        let k = uint16 (rnd.Next(0, 658))
        yield StructTuple(j,k)
}

let good_keys = seq{
    for k in 0us..658us do
        for j in 0u.. 3346862u do
            yield StructTuple(j,k)
}

module CmpHelpers = 
    let inline combine (h1:int) (h2:int) = (h1 <<< 5) + h1 ^^^ h2;

type StructTupleComparer<'T,'T2>() =
    let cmparer = EqualityComparer<Object>.Default
    interface IEqualityComparer<StructTuple<'T,'T2>> with
        member this.Equals (a,b) = cmparer.Equals(a.fst, b.fst) && cmparer.Equals(a.snd, b.snd)
        member this.GetHashCode (x) = CmpHelpers.combine (cmparer.GetHashCode(x.fst)) (cmparer.GetHashCode(x.snd)) 

type AutoGeneratedStructTupleComparer<'T,'T2>() =
    let cmparer = LanguagePrimitives.GenericEqualityComparer
    interface IEqualityComparer<StructTuple<'T,'T2>> with
        member this.Equals (a:StructTuple<'T,'T2>,b:StructTuple<'T,'T2>) = 
                LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericEqualityERIntrinsic<'T> a.fst b.fst
                    && LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericEqualityERIntrinsic<'T2> a.snd b.snd
        member this.GetHashCode (x:StructTuple<'T,'T2>) = 
                let mutable num = 0
                num <- -1640531527 + (LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericHashWithComparerIntrinsic<'T2> cmparer x.snd + ((num <<< 6) + (num >>> 2)))
                -1640531527 + (LanguagePrimitives.HashCompare.GenericHashWithComparerIntrinsic<'T> cmparer x.fst + ((num <<< 6) + (num >>> 2)));


let uniq (sq:seq<'a>) = Array.ofSeq (new HashSet<_>(sq)) 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let count = 15000000
    let keys = good_keys |> Seq.take count |> uniq
    printfn "good keys"
    check keys (new StructTupleComparer<_,_>()) "struct custom"
    check keys HashIdentity.Structural "struct auto"
    check keys (new AutoGeneratedStructTupleComparer<_,_>()) "struct auto explicit"


    let keys = bad_keys |> Seq.take count |>  uniq
    printfn "bad keys"
    check keys (new StructTupleComparer<_,_>()) "struct custom"
    check keys HashIdentity.Structural "struct auto"
    check keys (new AutoGeneratedStructTupleComparer<_,_>()) "struct auto explicit"



    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

output

good keys

struct custom 1.506934 sec 0.000000 collisions

struct auto 4.832881 sec 0.776863 collisions

struct auto explicit 3.166931 sec 0.776863 collisions

bad keys

struct custom 3.631251 sec 0.061893 collisions

struct auto 10.340693 sec 0.777034 collisions

struct auto explicit 8.893612 sec 0.777034 collisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opened issue in fsharp issue tracker. Accepted as a bug https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/343

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert on the overall algorithm used to produce auto-generated Equals and GetHashCode, but it just seems to produce something non-optimal here.  I don't know offhand if that is normal for a general-purpose auto-generated implementation, or if there are practical ways of auto-generating close-to-optimal implementations reliably.

It's worth noting that if you just use the standard tuple, the autogenerated hashing and comparison give the same collision rate and equal performance as your custom implementation.  And using the latest F# 4.0 bits (where there has recently been [a significant perf improvement](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/41ddc1628516f4e293b82856059a0e92ed04b1b3) in this area), the autogenerated stuff becomes significantly faster than the custom implementation.

My numbers:

```
// F# 3.1, struct tuples
good keys
  custom 0.951254 sec 0.000000 collisions
  auto 2.737166 sec 0.776863 collisions
bad keys
  custom 2.923103 sec 0.061869 collisions
  auto 7.706678 sec 0.777040 collisions

// F# 3.1, standard tuples
good keys
  custom 0.995701 sec 0.000000 collisions
  auto 0.965949 sec 0.000000 collisions
bad keys
  custom 3.091821 sec 0.061869 collisions
  auto 2.924721 sec 0.061869 collisions

// F# 4.0, standard tuples
good keys
  custom 1.018672 sec 0.000000 collisions
  auto 0.619066 sec 0.000000 collisions
bad keys
  custom 3.082988 sec 0.061869 collisions
  auto 1.829720 sec 0.061869 collisions
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use builin tuples because it is a reference type. And I can't use f# 4 in production. And problem is not in performance but in collisions. And as far as I know fsharp uses standard clr Tuple class so your last exaple shows nothing because my custom inmplementation is just a copy of standard tuple's implementation

Comment: Main problem is about collisions growth and it causes very big perf problems in our production code. Move from auto to custom reduced loading time of our server from several hours to several minutes.